# How to call two functions in a let..in.. in SML/NJ

Tags: smlnj

> I'm trying to call two separate functions within a function. One
>   function generates and presents a random List to a user and the other
>   function uses the random list and sorts it.

```
fun getNumber() = (
print "Please enter the number of integers: ";
let
    val str = valOf (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn)
    val i : int = valOf (Int.fromString str)
    in(
    randomList(i);  
    mergeSortDriver(randomList(i)))
end
);
```

> The above code only executes the `mergeSortDriver`. I've tried
>   multiple ways such as removing the parentheses, trying nested in
>   statements, and other methods but they do not work or they either give
>   me an error. So how can I call both of these functions and have both
>   present their data?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getNumber() = (
print "Please enter the number of integers: ";
let
    val str = valOf (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn)
    val i : int = valOf (Int.fromString str)
    in(
    randomList(i), 
    mergeSortDriver(randomList(i)))
end
);
```

> I needed to change the `;` to a `,` within the `in` statement